How to properly manage Aptly repositories for multiple distributions?
I am trying to manage a single Aptly repository for multiple distributions (Bionic and Focal) and architectures (amd64 and arm64). However, when I publish my snapshots, packages meant for one distribution are appearing in the other. Here’s what I’ve done so far:
aptly repo create -component=main -architectures=amd64,arm64 apt-dev

Add packages for Bionic and create a snapshot:
aptly repo add apt-dev /root/uploads/libdatachannel/libdatachannel_0.19.5_bionic_amd64.deb /root/uploads/libdatachannel/libdatachannel_0.19.5_bionic_arm64.deb 
aptly snapshot create apt-dev-bionic-snapshot from repo apt-dev

Publish the Bionic snapshot:
aptly publish snapshot -distribution=bionic -skip-signing apt-dev-bionic-snapshot

Add packages for Focal and create a snapshot:
aptly repo add apt-dev /root/uploads/libdatachannel/libdatachannel_0.19.5_focal_amd64.deb /root/uploads/libdatachannel/libdatachannel_0.19.5_focal_arm64.deb 
aptly snapshot create apt-dev-focal-snapshot from repo apt-dev

Publish the Focal snapshot:
aptly publish snapshot -distribution=focal -skip-signing apt-dev-focal-snapshot

The problem is that when I check the published repositories, I see packages meant for Bionic in the Focal repository as well.
What/how to work this out: to add more and more packages only to focal and then only to bionic and keep adding with more snapshots.
